# Side effects of cobertura

Tags: tomcat, logging, code-coverage, cobertura

After some efforts I finally get [cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) running correctly for my web application on a [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) server. Everything seems fine until I committed it to the svn and hudson finished(failed) his work. Without this build script I would have never (or later) discovered this issue. My build script tried to move the catalina.log to another directory but the catalina.log was missing. After some testing I assume that the pure presence of the cobertura.jar in classpath (without instrumenting anything) changes the logging behaviour of my tomcat.

Since I'm not that experienced with neither tomcat nor cobertura, can anyone confirm my observation. Are there anywhere any other side effects documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a log4j.properties in the cobertura jar files.

If you log with log4j, maybe this file is used for logging configuration (log4j takes the first log4.properties from the classpath and uses this).

you could remove this file from the lib OR make sure, that your logging configuration is first in the classpath.

If you supply -Dlog4j.debug=true log4j will tell you, which logging configuration file it uses.